# How to get an object to follow a path in Version 2.78, does not seem to work like it used to before?

Tags: tracking, path

Before I would simply create a path, and then add an object and the object would follow the path and would bend with the path if the object was like long enough, but now I can't get the object to follow the path even after adding the follow path constraint. And when I mess with the settings and do get the object to move about a little the object's point of origin moves along the path but the object remains rigid, is this an issue of blender? or have things been changed up?

Comment: what i mean by rigid is that the object will turn and "follow" the path but it no longer deforms to the path giving it that organic look of a soft material moving through a path.

Comment: Could you explain how you did it?

Comment: I created an object and i also added a path, I clicked on the object and added a constraint to follow path and pressed on animate path. Then I clicked on follow curve, and the object does move along the path. But the object itself remains rigid and wont bend as it moves along the path, the object itself rotates following the path but it retains its shape. Before a rectangular prism would actually bend around the curves to where it looked like it stretched and bent like if it was made of jelly.

Comment: It's hard to say without images, but it sounds like your mesh doesn't have enough geometry.  Try subdividing the mesh or adding loop cuts.

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember, the follow path constraint has always worked like that. The way to achieve what you are trying to do, is to add a curve modifier with the path as the deform object. Then animate the object along the same axis as the deformation axis of the modifier.